# How To Detect Embedded Video Encoded Bitrate

Tags: php, linux, video, detection, bitrate

If I want to embed a video file or stream that is not my own into an html page, is there any way that I can first detect the bitrate that the video was encoded at? Is there a way that it can be interrogated by a php routine (ideally) or some other linux based server routine to detect the bitrate?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi
```

This will output information about the video file, including the streams composing it, along with their bitrates. You can then use `grep` to filter out the specific bitrate you're interested in, or just execute the command from PHP with [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec) and parse the returned string to find the bitrate you're interested in.